# Paypal sendbox test account issue with no funds

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have problem with paypal sendbox testing account. I am trying to reproduce failing transaction when there is no enough funds but even when i make PERSONAL test account with 0$ i  always get transaction complited and money is always transferd on BUSSINESS account. When i try to pay i get this message:

> PayPal will use Discover XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0295 to fund this transaction
>   if your bank does not have enough funds.

So every time it draws money from that card, but when i try to delete that card from PERSONAL user i am rejected.

Do you know what can cause this problem? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create test accounts without bank / balance / card.
Though if that's the case and the account doesn't have any funds, the buyer will be asked to add a card to his account prior to being redirected back to your site.

If you'd like to test a card decline (which is different than testing a PayPal account with no funds), enable 'Negative testing' on your buyer test account and set the 'amount' the `AMT='104.86` for API error code 10486, or `AMT=106.06` for API error code 10606.

See also https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/ for more details about testing the API error 10486.